# Powershell generate a hexadecimal list

Tags: powershell

I am looking to generate a list of hex values using Powershell.  For instance, [0..100] creates an array of numbers 0-100.

How would I go about creating an array of values from 000-FFF?

Comment: Perfect.  Would you be able to explain how that works?  Also put it in as an answer so I can gove you a gold star.

Comment: Yes, make it an answer.  Explanation:  0x is a prefix for a hexadecimal number.  The number is actually stored in binary, regardless of whether it's specified in hex or decimal.  Thus 0..4095 and 0..0xfff mean exactly the same thing.  As for the x3 that's just a format rule for the conversion to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following expression:

```
0..0xfff|% ToString X3
```

Where:

- `0` is zero.
- `..` is range operator.
- `0xfff` is integer literal for 4095 in hexadecimal form.
- `|` is pipe operator.
- `%` is alias for `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.
- `ToString` is name of method to call.
- `X3` is parameter for method. It is [standard numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString) that means, format as hexadecimal number with at least three digits.

So:

- `0..0xfff` creates an array of numbers 0-4095.
- `|` pass elements of array to next command.
- `% ToString X3` format each number as hexadecimal with at least three digits.

Comment: I am really wondering about your super shortened version. Is there any documentation for that? I would write ... |% { $_.ToString("X3") }

Comment: @Santhos `% -?` or [online version](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bea187c1-37b5-4fc7-9422-d29820643a4d.aspx): *Operation statement. You can also write a operation statement, which is much more like natural language. You can use the operation statement to specify a property value or call a method. Operation statements were introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.*